# Swift Delegate is never called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols, uicontainerview

I know the question is already here in the forum but I don't know why my delegate doesn't work. I work with them for the first time, by the way.

Here is the code

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ContainerViewControllerDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let controller = ContainerViewController()
        controller.containerDelegate = self

    }

    func didScrollChangeAppearanceBarButtonItem(change: Bool) {
        if(change == true){
            print("true")
        }else{
            print("false")
        }
    }

}
```

ContainerView:

```
protocol ContainerViewControllerDelegate {
     func didScrollChangeAppearanceBarButtonItem(change: Bool)
}

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate{

    var containerDelegate: ContainerViewControllerDelegate?

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        if(velocity.y>0) {
            containerDelegate?.didScrollChangeAppearanceBarButtonItem(change: false)
            print("1")

        } else {
            containerDelegate?.didScrollChangeAppearanceBarButtonItem(change: true)
            print("2")
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do: When I scroll I want to send a bool to my ViewController. When the bool == true I want to something and when the bool == false I want to do something else.

I hope somebody can help me :)

Comment: If you are using storyboard `ContainerViewController()` is not the instance in the storyboard. You need the real reference by segue or instantiation.

Comment: Is `print("1")` & `print("2")` called? When that's the case, is `containerDelegate` nil? Could you make `let controller = ContainerViewController()` an instance var? Could be an issue of scope. What's `controller` exactly?

Comment: @Larme 1. Print(„1“) and print(„2“) is called. Where I should prove if containerDelegate = nil? After I print („1“)? 2. Sorry, what is an instance var? 3. controller should be the same as ContainerViewController()

Comment: @Larme Yes, containerDelegate is nil. How can I fix that?

Comment: Of course it's `nil` because it's not the proper instance. As I said the instance in the storyboard and `controller` are two completely different objects.

Comment: @vadian You were right. How can I access my ContainerView?

Comment: Please re-read my first comment. *You need the real reference by segue or instantiation.*

Comment: @Thanks a lot vadian. I think now I have done it right but my controllerDelegate is stil nil. Here my code: `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContainerViewController") as! ContainerViewController;
        controller.containerDelegate = self`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of this:

```
let controller = ContainerViewController() 
controller.containerDelegate = self
```

create the variable outside viewDidLoad():

```
var controller:ContainerViewController! 
override func viewDidLoad() { 
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    controller = ContainerViewController() 
    controller.containerDelegate = self 
}
```

The reason is that the controller being initialized inside the viewDidLoad gets deallocated once the viewDidLoad function reaches its end

**Edit**

I will elaborate, if you are trying to access your other view controller by segue, this is a wrong way. Instead do this:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("your identifier", sender: self)
```

then add a function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Your identifier") {
        guard let controller = segue.destination as? ContainerViewController else { return }
        controller.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my code but but it's still not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: When I create the function I get the error: "Method does not override any method from its superclass"

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating a ContainerViewController, which is deallocated about a microsecond later when the code leaves viewDidLoad, because there are no references to it.